# Skip a specific values from acts_as_taggable related item display(loop)-ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

This is my show method of controller.

```
def show
  @relatedimages = Photo.tagged_with(@photo.tag_list, :any =>     true).shuffle[1..4]
end
```

I wanted to display related photos based on tags, in photo show page.And hide the photo which user viewing, from related images.

This is my view-show.html.erb

```
<% @relatedimages.each do |photo| %>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="relatedimage">
      <% next if @photo? %>
       <%=image_tag photo.file.url(:thumb)%>

    </div>
  </div>
 <%end%>
```

And Im getting nothing for the reslut. Not displaying any of related images. But I wanted to skip the current image only.

help me to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
def show
  @relatedimages = Photo.tagged_with(
    @photo.tag_list, any: true).
    shuffle[1..4] - @photo
end
```

because you can do operations with an arrays with simple + - operators

Comment: and remember to remove next if @photo? from the view

Answer (score 2):

I would at a scope to your model:

```
# in app/models/photo.rb
scope :similar_photos, ->(photo, number) {
  where.not(id: photo.id).  # excludes the current photo from the query
  order('RANDOM()').        # 'RANDOM' works with postgresql and sqlite, whereas mysql uses 'RAND'
  tagged_with(photo.tag_list, any: true)
}
```

Then it is just this in your controller:

```
@relatedimages = Photo.similar_photos(@photo).limit(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
<% next if @photo? %>
```

try

```
<% if photo != @photo %>
```

Another suggestion here would be to rename @photo to @current_photo or another more meaningful term, that way(photo != @current_photo) your code would be more readable.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved with <% if photo != @photo %> . and I have to drop question mark. Thank you. again

Comment: Yes, sorry about that